# Evaluating multidimensional polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Are there efficient algorithms to construct optimal evaluators of multivariable polynomials?  Here, an 'evaluator' can be thought of as an algorithm or description of how to evaluate a specific polynomial at a given point (and an 'optimal evaluator' one that requires the least amount of computation.)  I might expect something analogous to Horner's rule to be optimal in the generic dense setting, but things could become more interesting for polynomials with a substantial fraction of zero coefficients.